# No hebrew shows in DVI (CTRL+D)

Tags: lyx, ubuntu, hebrew

I've installed LyX with culmus-latex on Ubuntu 14.04 and set settings according to this tutorial: http://gadial.net/Documents/LyX%20Guide.pdf

My problem is that when I preview some document in hebrew with CTRL+D I don't see any hebrew.
Where there was supposed to be hebrew I see nothing, blank space.

What could be the problem?

Answer (score 1):

Hebrew export works for me in LyX on Ubuntu. If I go to File > Open > Examples and select splash.lyx, I can export it to DVI or to PDF via ps2pdf, pdflatex, and also XeTeX if I use FreeSans system fonts.

An easy way to install TeX Live in Ubuntu and get Hebrew support is to use [install-tl-ubuntu](https://github.com/scottkosty/install-tl-ubuntu) as follows

```
sudo ./install-tl-ubuntu --hebrew
```

The relevant part of the installation for hebrew is

```
  mkdir "/tmp/HebrewFonts" &&
  cd "/tmp/HebrewFonts" &&
  wget "http://ftp.us.debian.org/debian/pool/main/i/ivritex/ivritex_1.1.1-6_all.deb" &&
  ar x "ivritex_1.1.1-6_all.deb" && tar -xf "data.tar.gz" &&
  rsync -a "usr/share/texmf/" "$(kpsewhich -var-value TEXMFLOCAL)"
```

Comment: Ivritex is obsolete in new tex distributions (from around 2005), as its changes (except for the fonts) were merged into `babel`. To get Hebrew fonts, the recommended way is to install [culmus-latex](http://www.guyrutenberg.com/culmus-latex).

Comment: @Guy This is good to know, thanks. I would like to test replacing it with culmus-latex, but is there a direct link to "the latest version"? I can download the 0.7-1 by clicking through source forge, but for the script I would need a direct link. Alternatively I could bundle it but I would prefer not to do that.